# Searching current folder for spreadsheets and changing value in specific cell of each file found

Tags: google-apps-script

New to Google Apps script here, but have some coding experience. I want to scan *current* folder for spreadsheets. For each spreadsheet found, I want to change the value in a specific cell (say cell F16 in "Sheet1") to "Q1 FY16". Here is what I have so far:

```
function myFunction() {

var folderID ="0BxfGszImm3D9flpVlWXd4bjQ";
var topFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
Logger.log(topFolder.getName());
var filesList = topFolder.getFiles();

while (filesList.hasNext()) {
    var file = filesList.next();
    Logger.log(file.getName());
    file.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("F16").setValue("Q1 FY16");
 }
}
```

There are two main problems:

1. I have to specify a folder ID in this and I don't want to. I want the code to run in the current directory (and eventually I will make it recursive to scan all subfolders as well).
2. The File class doesn't have the "getSheetByName()" or "getRange()" methods, but I don't know how to cast the files into Spreadsheets.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

1. Where will you be launching this script from? They are no way of launching script directly from google drive.
2. to Be able to use the getSheetByName() and the getRange() you need to open the file as a spreadsheet. 
   instead of using this line:

   ```
   file.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("F16").setValue("Q1 FY16");
   ```

You should use something like this :

```
try {
SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId()).getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("F16").setValue("Q1 FY16");
} 
catch(e){}
```

you need to use the try - catch since some of the files won't be spreadsheet and give and error when trying to use the SpreadsheetApp.openById().

I hope this helps you a bit, I'll try to update this answer once I get more information for the first part.

Best of luck.

Comment: Ok so I guess there is no way around having to provide an initial folder ID to start from? I was hoping to launch from a standalone script in whatever folder I was in - but I suppose I can attach the script to a spreadsheet in my root drive and specify an ID. <br> My 2nd question is - do I HAVE to open all the spreadsheets before changing a value inside them or can I just change the value with them closed? Would save a lot of time if the latter - especially with hundreds of spreadsheets.

Comment: Hi OrangeBender - or anyone else - would you be able to help me with the rest of my questions? :) Thanks!

Comment: Okay so you want to move your script file in a folder and use this folder as the root folder?  If by "open all the spreadsheets" you mean the "SpreadsheeApp.openById" then yes since your script needs to know where you're trying to write information.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help so far Orangebender - I'm inching closer to the solution thanks to your help.

1) So in order for me to edit the value inside a Google Spreadsheet, I actually have to OPEN it before changing the value?

2) And yes, I want to run my script from whichever folder I'm currently in, without having to specify a folder ID.

Comment: Ahh, I just discovered that the "openByID" function only opens the file in memory, rather than actually opening it and displaying it on screen. This works for me perfectly in this instance.

For future reference, if I want the file to physically open and display - and then I want to close it - what are the functions for that? I couldn't find them in the API.

Comment: From a script file you can no longer open a new tab or window in the browser without user interaction. This was a modification made by the google script team on Oct 26, 2012.

Comment: As of now I didn't find any way of finding the folder ID of the location of the script file. You can do it with almost any other file but not a direct script. If you were to use a Doc or spreadsheet and use the script linked to that form you could make it work. I'll continue to search a bit later today and give you more details later.

Comment: I didn't find anyway to get the script folder ID. Any luck on your side @Fowzee ?

Comment: No luck unfortunately - I dont think it exists :(